# SQL syntax error in PHP code, even though command runs in command line

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make some SQL commands in XAMPP. My query returns following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kayttajat ( id INT(10) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT, tunn' at line 2

I can't find the syntax error. **And when I run the exact same command by copy-paste in command line, it works.** So do I need some different syntax in PHP code? 
Also if I remove the first command, the error message moves to `[...] right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rivit [...]`. If I remove second command the error comes from third command and so on. I really don't understand where the error is.

```
$query='
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS asdgfhj;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kayttajat
(
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tunnus1 varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    tunnus2 varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    nimi varchar(32),
    nimi2 varchar(32),
    oikeus INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rivit
(
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sivu INT(10) NOT NULL,
    kayttaja INT(10) NOT NULL,
    sana varchar(500),
    kommentti varchar(1000),
    aika TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    muutos TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sivut
(
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nimi varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    ohje varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
    salaisuus INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
';

$mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
```

Comment: Maybe change to [Multiple Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)? I don't think you can run more than one with [query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`query()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) method is designed to execute a **single** query not multiple ones.

What you are looking for is [`multi_query()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to execute multiple queries separated by a semicolon.

```
$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are great!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`multi_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) if you want execute many queries with one command.

Also you don't select database which will used for `insert` statements.
You should add `asdgfhj` prefix for all tables or use [`USE asdgfhj`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html) after `create table` statement.

example with prefix:

```
<?php
$query='
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS asdgfhj;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS asdgfhj.kayttajat
(
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tunnus1 varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    tunnus2 varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    nimi varchar(32),
    nimi2 varchar(32),
    oikeus INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
';

$mysqli->multi_query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
```

example with [`use`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html) statement:

```
<?php
$query='
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS asdgfhj;
USE asdgfhj;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kayttajat
(
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tunnus1 varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    tunnus2 varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    nimi varchar(32),
    nimi2 varchar(32),
    oikeus INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
';

$mysqli->multi_query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
```